# cannot use definition in .d.ts in spec files

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

the editor states error saying that the property I added to Request from express doesn't exist.

```
declare module Express {
  interface Request {
    idAnunciante?: string,
    locals?: any
  }
}
```

in my code is like this

somefile.spec.ts
const request: Request

```
request.locals <<---locals doesn's exist
```

the declaration in somefile.ts is ok

```
request.locals <<-- ok
```

Comment: I am starting to think that is visual code bug. I don't know.